# how to load markers of only viewing part of map?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my code, I am loading markers from JSON data using Google API. It is loading all map icons on one go and its taking approx. 2 min to load which is a lot of time. Is there any way to load markers which are in screen area.
1. how to load markers fast.
2. Icon loading is not stoping.
3. How to make cluster and load it in one go

```
   @Override
protected List < Product > doInBackground(Void...params) {

   HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

   DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

   SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
   SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
   socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
   registry.register(new Scheme("http", socketFactory, 443));
   SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

   // Set verifier
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products");

   URLConnection urlConn = null;
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   try {
       URL url = new URL(this.serverUrl);
       urlConn = url.openConnection();
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       String line;
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           stringBuffer.append(line);
       }

       JSONObject response = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());

       List < Product > products = new ArrayList < > ();
       HashMap < String, Bitmap > iconsMap = new HashMap < > ();
       try {
           JSONArray productsJSON = response.getJSONArray("all_products");
           for (int ixProduct = 0; ixProduct < productsJSON.length(); ixProduct++) {
               JSONObject productJSON = productsJSON.getJSONObject(ixProduct);
               String mapIconStr = productJSON.getString("map_icon");
               URI uri = new URI(mapIconStr);
               String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
               String iconName = segments[segments.length - 1];

               // percetn-encode URL
               String mapIconPath = mapIconStr.substring(0, mapIconStr.indexOf(iconName));
               String iconUrlString = mapIconPath + URLEncoder.encode(iconName, "UTF-8");

               // replace "http:" with "https:"
               iconUrlString = iconUrlString.replace("http:", "https:");

               Log.d("Icon Load ", "doInBackground: " + iconUrlString);
               Bitmap bmp;
               if (!iconsMap.containsKey(iconUrlString)) {
                   bmp = getBitmapFromURL(iconUrlString);
                   // populate map with unique icons
                   iconsMap.put(iconUrlString, bmp);
               } else {
                   bmp = iconsMap.get(iconUrlString);
               }

               if (bmp != null) {
                   try {
                       Product product = new Product();
                       product.id = productJSON.getString("ID");
                       product.name = productJSON.getString("post_title");
                       product.lat = productJSON.getDouble("latitude");
                       product.lon = productJSON.getDouble("longitude");
                       id = product.id;
                       System.out.println("my Id stored" + id);
                       bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() * 2.5), (int)(bmp.getHeight() * 2.5), true);
                       product.icon = bmp;
                       products.add(product);
                   } catch (Exception ignore) {}

               }

           }

       } catch (JSONException ex) {
           Log.e("App", "Failure", ex);
       }

       return products;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       Log.e("App", "yourDataTask", ex);
       return null;
   } finally {
       if (bufferedReader != null) {
           try {
               bufferedReader.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }


 }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List < Product > products) {
       if (products != null) {
           for (final Product product: products) {

           Marker marker = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(new LatLng(product.lat, product.lon))
               .title(product.name)
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(product.icon)));
           markerIds.put(marker, product.id);


       }
       if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
           mDialog.dismiss();
       }
   }

   }
   }
```

Comment: where is code to add marker ??

Comment: pls view code edit

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking long time cause of the Bitmap you are using for markers, just for a proof remove the bitmap from on post execute and check the time. like this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List < Product > products) {
   if (products != null) {
       Log.e("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
       for (final Product product: products) {

       Marker marker = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(new LatLng(product.lat, product.lon))
           .title(product.name)
       markerIds.put(marker, product.id);


   }
   Log.e("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
   if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
       mDialog.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Did you tried git library https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils
it plots all markets very efficiently without making the phone slow and efficiently.

Comment: I try your code but still, it takes the same amount of time to load data.

Comment: can you show me these two logs Log.e("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());    Log.e("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: E/startTime: 1518090205012

Comment: E/endTime: 1518090388029

Comment: did you removed this line .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(product.icon))); or not ???

Comment: first fix one issue, is that fixed ??